# Getting NameError: uninitialized constant when trying to assign belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have two models like the following:

```
module MainModule
  module SubModule
    class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :rooms
    end
  end
end

module MainModule
  module SubModule
    class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :home
    end
  end
end
```

if I do the following, I get an error:

```
> home.rooms << room
=> NameError: uninitialized constant Room
(Failed)
> home.rooms
=>  #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
(Success)
```

But if I update the Home model:

```
..
has_many :rooms, class_name: "MainModule::SubModule::Room"
..
> home.rooms << room
=> #<MainModule::SubModule::Room id: 1, ...>
```

For some reason, I can get the associated rooms but can't assign a new one. What did I miss here?

Comment: Because has_many :rooms association is expecting a Room mode but you have MainModule::SubModule::Room.

Comment: That's what I thought until home.rooms is working properly

Comment: did u try  `belongs_to :home, class_name: 'MainModule::SubModule::Home'`

Comment: @AsadAli Yes I did. The question is, why, without specify the class name, calling associated objects works but assigning associated object isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure your models are in subdirectories under the app/models directory in Rails. I have something like this:

```
$ ls -1R app/models
  main_module

  app/models/main_module:
  sub_module

  app/models/main_module/sub_module:
  home.rb
  room.rb
```

With that structure, I was able to do the following in the Rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> home = MainModule::SubModule::Home.new
=> #<MainModule::SubModule::Home id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> home.name = 'Home'
=> "Home"
irb(main):003:0> home.save
=> true
irb(main):004:0> room = MainModule::SubModule::Room.new
=> #<MainModule::SubModule::Room id: nil, name: nil, home_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0> room.name = 'Room'
=> "Room"
irb(main):006:0> room.save
=> true
irb(main):007:0> home.rooms << room
=> [#<MainModule::SubModule::Room id: 1, name: "Room", home_id: 1, created_at: "2016-01-06 14:28:06", updated_at: "2016-01-06 14:28:13">]
```

Comment: Like I said, I specify modules of both Home and Room to be MainModule::SubModule. If I, in any case, happened to placed them in wrong subdirectories, Rails will throw LoadError long before I run into this issue

Comment: Like this, "LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Home, expected /Users/Tar_Tw45/Documents/Ruby on Rails/MyApp/app/models/home.rb to define it"

Answer (score 0):

How about the following(I haven't tried it):

```
module MainModule
  module SubModule
    class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :rooms
    end
  end
end

module MainModule
  module SubModule
    class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :home
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I forgot to write subclassing in the original question. Same result anyway.

Comment: Ok, I will delete my answer shortly.